# Why can't I see the Belongs-on ... Vote-to-close options on SO?

Tags: support, vote-to-close

Did I miss a change?  Should things that appear to warrant migration to MSO/SU/SF just be closed as off-topic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is now a second screen after selecting off-topic:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you click `Off Topic` a new screen appears where you you can either migrate it or close it as off-topic.

See [this blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/new-question-migration-paths/) for further information